# Machine selection probability question

Tags: probability

An assembly line is turned on, and machine A starts making widgets numbered from $1, 2, $ etc. while machine B inspects them. Each time machine A outputs two widgets into a large bin, machine B takes one out for inspection (and does not return it). This process is called 1 iteration. If machine B selects the widgets at random, what's the probability that:

a) widget $1$ will still be in the bin after $n$ iterations?

b) any widget in the bin will stay there forever?

c) a particular widget of the two placed in the bin at iteration $x$ still be in the bin after iteration $y$ assuming $x \le y$?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (c), we should be able to induce (a) and (b).

Since each time machine A outputs two widgets and B takes one out for inspection, number of widgets after $n$ iterations is $n$. A particular widget iteration $x$ still be in the bin after iteration $y$ if it's not removed during the $(x+1)^{th}$ iteration ($p_1 = \frac{x}{x+1}$) and the $(x+2)^{th}$ iteration ($p_2 = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$) and ... and the $y^{th}$ iteration ($p_{y-x+1} =\frac{y}{y+1}$).

$$P = \frac{x}{x+1}\frac{x+1}{x+2}\dots \frac{y}{y+1} = \frac{x}{y+1}.$$

Comment: can you check if i'm following correctly? so by this reasoning a) would be $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and b) would be $\frac{x}{y+1}$ which would be 0 as $y \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @shoestringfries Yes! That's what I got, too.